# Read drupal log programmatically

Tags: 7

I want to get all the logs, which are available under `admin/reports/dblog` as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Below are the two approaches, I can think of:

1. Access logs programmatically in Python or PHP
2. Download the database as a SQL file and read the database

I am not sure if the above approaches are possible or not. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you have the dblog module enabled, that data is in the database, so you can use whatever language or method you want to extract and analyse it.

The data is kept in the `watchdog` table.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see the logs in `watchdog` table. However, the message column has some references such as `Login attempt failed for %user`. How to see the value of `%user` for this case?

Comment: Those are placeholders, the values are in the `variables` column as a serialised PHP string. For a simple combination you can use `$message = strtr($record->message, unserialize($record->variables));`

Answer (score 1):

I see three main options:

**Use Syslog**

Use the [Syslog core module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/syslog/overview):

> The Syslog module logs events by sending messages to the logging
>   facility of your web server's operating system.

Using this module you can access all log messages thanks to the syslog subsystem.

**Access the data directly**

As Clive suggests, use the data that DBlog saves in the `watchdog` table. The tables's structure for Drupal 7 is like this:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| wid       | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| type      | varchar(64)         | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| message   | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| variables | longblob            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| severity  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| link      | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location  | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| referer   | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hostname  | varchar(128)        | NO   |     |         |                |
| timestamp | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The error message is in the `message` column, and the values of the tokens in the message are in the `variables` column. To get the complete message you can use the function t, as dblog does:

```
 $output = t($event->message, unserialize($event->variables));
```

In this case you probably access the data after the event is created and processed by drupal, in a batch process. Useful if you just want to store messages but not if you want to react in real time.

**Hook to the watchdog**

You can write your own module and get all watchdog messages when they are delivered. To do this you have to implement the [hook_watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7.x). In this case you receive the event at the time it's generated.